# The value of loop variable at the end of a loop in the insertion sort

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, sorting

I am looking at the algorithm of the insertion sort:

Input: $A[1 \dots n]$

```
 for j <- 2 to n
    key <- A[j]
    i <- j-1
    while (i>0 and A[i]>key)
          A[i+1] <- A[i]
          i <- i-1
    end
    A[i+1] <- key
 end
```

There is the following sentence:

$$\text{At the beginning of each iteration "for" ,the subsequence } A[1 \dots j-1] \\ \text{ consists of the elements that are from the beginning at these positions,  }\\ \text{ but sorted with the desired way.}$$

The proof of this sentence is the following:

> - **Initial control**, when $j=2:$ The sentence is true,because the subsequence  $A[1]$ \text{ is sorted in a trivial way
> - **Preservation control:**  The algorithm moves the elements $ A[j-1], A[j-2], \dots $  to the right side,till the right position for $ A[j] $ is found.
> - **Verification of the result:**  When the loop "for" ends, $j$ has the value $n+1$. The subsequence is now $ A[1 \dots n]$,  which is now sorted.

Could you explain me why $j$ has the value $n+1$, when the loop "for" ends?

Can $j$ take the value $n+1$, although at the algorithm it is: for $j\leftarrow 2$ to $n$?

Comment: Is it doing anything weird with j=n+1 like causing an error or writing over memory?

Comment: Is it possible that $j$ takes this value,although at the algorithm it is for j<-2 to n ? :/

Answer (score 2):

Some languages have for loops that do this. It goes through the content of the for loop, then it updates j, then it checks j. So if we go through the loop for j=n, it will update j to be n+1 and THEN check if we want to use j if it's between 2 and n. So it decides it's not and exits. But it already incremented j. That is only if you aren't getting any unusual behavior or faults.

So, if it's not performing incorrectly and it's just j being n+1, then it's harmless and part of the nature of the for loop. However, this may not be the issue if you're getting an error or wrong sorting.

Comment: I understand..So,if I want to write a code in C,would it be right like that:

$$for (j=1; j<n; ) \{ $$
    $$key=A[j];$$
    $$ i=j-1;$$
    $$ while ((i>=0) \&\& (A[i]>key)) \{ $$
          $$ A[i+1]=A[i]; $$
          $$ i=i-1; $$
   $$ \}$$
    $$A[i+1]=key; $$
    $$j++; $$
$$\}$$

?

Comment: Move the j++ from where it is to the location in this line: for(j=1; j<n; j++). Otherwise you are correct. And it's just the nature of C that j ends up at n in this case. However it doesn't perform the contents of the for loop for j=n.

Comment: So,if we want to have $n+1$ at the end,we can only do this with a while?

Comment: No. You'd just have to have the for loop set to run on n as well. So we change j<n to j<=n. However be careful with C. Because your arrays start indexing at 0. So if you have n element j=n doesn't exist.

Comment: I understand..Could you explain me how I can find the cost of the insertion sort?

Comment: You would be better to ask these kinds of questions over at Computer Science StackExchange or at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop is equivalent to a while loop:

```
for j <- 2 to n
    <stuff>
end
```

is equivalent to

```
j = 2
while j <= n
    <stuff>
    j <- j+1
end
```

On the last pass through the loop, on entering the loop body, j will have the value n.  It will be incremented to n+1 at the bottom of the loop body and then the comparison will fail causing control to exit the loop.  Thus, immediately after the loop, the value of j is n+1.

Comment: I understand..thank you very much!!!

Comment: And,is this also right?

$$for (j=1; j<n; ) \{ $$
    $$key=A[j];$$
    $$ i=j-1;$$
    $$ while ((i>=0) \&\& (A[i]>key)) \{ $$
          $$ A[i+1]=A[i]; $$
          $$ i=i-1; $$
   $$ \}$$
    $$A[i+1]=key; $$
    $$j++; $$
$$\}$$

?

Comment: @evinda:  Maybe.  It is at least different from the while loop in your original question.  To address this:  "for(j= **2** ; j<=n; )".  Also the last line can be moved to the third (empty) position in the for as:  "for(j=2; j<=n; **j++**)"

Comment: But..then $j$ won't have the value $n+1$ at the end,right?

And..something else..could you give me a hint how I can find the cost of the insertion sort?

Comment: @evinda: On the last pass through the for loop, $j$ must be $\leq n$, so is $=n$.  The for loop is rewritten exactly as the while loop in my answer, so the equivalent while loop has the increment at the bottom and $j$ will be $n+1$ after the loop body.

Comment: @evinda:  How many times does the body of the inner while loop run?  Then, how many times does the outer loop run, causing the inner loop to run?

Comment: The for loop runs $n-2+1=n-1$ times and the while loop at most $n-1$ times,so what can I conclude from that?

Comment: @evinda:  The while loop runs between zero and $j$ times.  It is run at most once during the first pass through the for loop, at most twice during the second pass, at most three times during the third.  Do you know what $\sum_{j=1}^n j$ is?  This would upper bound the number of times the inner loop body is executed.

Comment: Eric So,is the cost for the loop "while" $\displaystyle{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ ?

Comment: @evinda:  Computing "cost" requires assigning elementary costs to elementary operations.  If we assign the cost $1$ to the entire body of the inner loop (which body is not elementary, so this choice is suspect) and $0$ to the rest of the outer loop (which choice is perhaps more suspect), we get the cost you came up with.  The choice of a detailed cost model can be very complicated -- for instance the increments and decrements of $i$ and $j$ can be cheap if $i$ and $j$ are hardware integer types and expensive if $i$ and $j$ are "bignum"s.  So, what's your detailed computational cost model?